# How to reduce multi-line text using something like zoom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***The essence of the task***   is to make a rubber page, which will decrease as much as the screen shrinks as it is in default size. This page is multilingual and compared to Russian or English text, German is simply huge.

***The essence of the problem***   is that I have a block with fixed sizes in percent, let's say  `6%`  of height and  `30%`  of width. This block contains a text container, say `<p> </p>`. This container contains multi-line text that fills the entire container. When changing the language, the text is translated in real time and in the German translation it becomes longer.
***Question***   such as how to make the text smaller due to  `zoom`  or  `font-size`  or some other parameter? It is also worth considering that the text should not be separated using `<br/>`
Использовал уже

- ReactFitText
- FitText
- Fitty

```
import React from 'react';
import ratioFrame from '../../components/ratioFrame';
import withLocale from '../../modules/translate/withLocale';

class PageBFE extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { size, translate, formatText } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="content bgPage2" style={size}>
            <div style={{ fontSize: formatText(5.55) }} className="text-title">{translate('presentation1.page2.text1')}</div>
          <ul className="text-box-content2  liStyle" style={{ fontSize: formatText(3.41) }}>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text2')}</li>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text3')}</li>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text4')}</li>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text5')}</li>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text6')}</li>
            <li>{translate('presentation1.page2.text7')}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withLocale(ratioFrame(PageBFE));
```

**size** - size of the area where all the content is located

**FormatText** - text size relative to screen in vh or vw

```
.text-title {
  margin: 5.8% 5.6% 0 5.6%;
  width: 88.8%;
  background: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 6.315%;
  max-height: 6.315%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

class SizeText extends React.Component {
  state={
    zoom: 1
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const box1 = this.element1.offsetHeight;
    const box2 = this.element2.offsetHeight;
    const zoom = box1 / box2;
    this.setState(zoom)
  }

  render() {
    const { content, className1, className2, formatText } = this.props;
    const { zoom } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        ref={(element) => {
          this.element1 = element;
        }}
        className={className1}
        style={{ fontSize: formatText(5.55) }}
      >
        <div
          ref={(element) => {
            this.element2 = element;
          }}
          style={{zoom: zoom}}
          className={className2}
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SizeText;
```

content - Text

className1 - Class for parent block

className2 - Class for child block

formatText - text size (font-size) in vh/vw is relatively smaller

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to get the [dimensions of the screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) and then use `scale` [css function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) based on the mathematical operations to set the scale value

Comment: I also thought about this, but for this I need to get the height of the parent block, in order to know the maximum and the height of the child block, in order to know if the block with the text exceeds the permissible size
If it is too high, then take the multiplier from the difference between the maximum and the higher value (This is kind of like a crutch, but so far this is the only solution)

Comment: I do agree, for that you should use the offsetHeight of the element https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: Yes, I use this design, only it gives me the wrong data.
`document.getElemtntByClassname('.element')` gives me the exact length, but when I use `document.getElemtntByClassname('.element').offsetHeight` - it packs some kind of obscure data. Thank you for helping, now I will try again. 4 days without advancement with this task

Comment: The getElementByClassName returns a HTMLCollection, which is very similar to an array. What you are looking for is the height of a specific element so you should pick it from the HTMLCollection or use getElementById instead.

You can check HTMLCollection documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: I tried your option, but the problem remained the same.
My container, from which I determine the height, has a height of 80px, and in the console shows 160px. The text does not move to another line, so it is not clear why it is 2 times increasing the height.
If I add more text so that it jumps to another line, it still shows 160px, and when I add so much text so that it occupies the entire second line, it shows 240px

Comment: I understood why the values in the console and in fact diverge
Because my text is calculated in vh / vw, but now it’s not clear how to avoid this